# Getting a 'Duplicate entry' error even though I'm using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm currently doing a project where I'm going through thousands of data packets. Now, I log each of those packets IP and MAC address along with some other information. To store all this I use MySQL and my script is written in Node.js. Currently I'm dealing with well over 40k packets per second, so the database traffic is pretty intense. Now, the tricky part is that IP and MAC addresses should be linked together so they only exist once in the table. Therefore I've set both of them to UNIQUE. However, when I query the database I get an error:

```
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff' for key 'mac_UNIQUE'
```

And even though I'm using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, it spits the error.
My database is set up like this:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `hosts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `mac` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `method` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `netbiosName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ip_UNIQUE` (`ip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `mac_UNIQUE` (`mac`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1862 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1$$
```

And this is my query in Node.js with the node_mysql library:

```
mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO ' + mysqlTable + ' (ip, mac, method) VALUES(?, ?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ip=?, mac=?, method=?',
                    [ipAddress, macAddress, method, ipAddress, macAddress, method]);
```

I really can't figure out a way of getting this to work.

**UPDATE:** I think I might be better of using the IP address as the UNIQUE key for a number of reasons. The question remains though, is this possible?

Comment: My guess is you have an UNIQUE constraint on ip and mac. You insert a row with an existing ip and it tries to update it to a new mac which also exists but at another row. Not sure if this makes sense...

Comment: In here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html is states  In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.

Comment: what's your table trying to accomplish? MAC<->IP mappings aren't 1:1, especially in DHCP environments.

Comment: @MarcB I want the index to be up to date all the time. If the user gets assigned a new IP. But you might be onto something. Should I completely drop that 1:1 relationship between the MAC and IP? And which should be the primary key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

*In general, you should try to avoid using an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause on tables with multiple unique indexes.*

The insert tries to replace the exsisting IP with your current IP but then fails to put the MAC as you already have it in your DB. An example is you have a record with IP 127.0.0.1. And you have a record with MAC address 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff' You insert a new record with this IP and MAC address 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'. MySQL updates the record with the IP to the same IP - 127.0.0.1, but fails to finish the update as this MAC address already exsist in the DB.

Hope I managed to explain it well :)

If IP address to MAC address relationship is 1:1 they should use a composite key and then you can do ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: Is there a command that solves this issue by deleting the conflicting one?

Comment: I do not think so, probably a query needs to be run prior to INSERT in order to check for consistency, or change your keys. I would make a unique key on the MAC and the IP (combine them in one unique key). depends on what you are willing to achieve.

Comment: But if they used composite keys, a MAC address or and IP address could still exist twice, eliminating the need for UNIQUE keys. Or?

Comment: A composite key on both of them will mean that the combinaiton of IP / MAC is unique, but you may have the same IP or MAC address multiple times in the DB table. If you want ot store the unique IPs and unique MACs, store them in two separate tables. This is the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understood your problem correctly:

If you want **each pair** of ip/mac to be unique (it makes sense) you must have a composed unique key and not **two unique keys**, as you have.

In a DHCP env, each MAC addr can/will have multiple IPs over time.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, thank you very much! :) I've updated my question, and will make the IP Address the only unique key. My question still remains though. If there was a 1:1 relationship between the two, would it be possible?

Comment: Sure. Create a composite unique key on IP+MAC. And, of you want to have fast searchs on IPs/MACs create isolated non unique indexes on each field.

Comment: I have selected the other one as the answer as I think it will be more substantial to other people coming by that has the same troubles. Your question answers part of my specific question, and I highly appreciate that. Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Nevertheless, I feel somewhat frustrated since the one who pointed out your problem was me... The oher answer was edited after that. But I understand your option. Anyway, thanks for explaining.

Comment: Yes I feel your pain. Though both answers are correct, I have to choose only one. If I could choose both, I would do that. :)